# Use organization if there is no author or editor for alphabetic style label

Tags: biblatex, biber

How can I use the organization in a publication as a replacement for author or editor when generating the citation label for the `alphabetic` style in biblatex?

I know that I can use the `label` field to manually assign a label, but an automatic solution would be nice.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{Wikipedia2017,
 date = {2016-12-20},
 organization = {Wikipedia},
 title = {Resource contention},
 url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=755891262},
 urldate = {2017-04-26}
}
@techreport{Volpe2000,
 author = {Volpe, Richard and Nesnas, Issa A. D. and Estlin, Tara and Mutz, Darren and Petras, Richard and Das, Hari},
 date = {2000},
 institution = {Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology},
 location = {Pasadena, California},
 title = {{CLARAty}: Coupled Layer Architecture for Robotic Autonomy}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a test~\autocite{Wikipedia2017}. And this works as expected~\autocite{Volpe2000}.

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to see some label like `Wik16` instead.

Comment: Add `label = {Wik}`.

Comment: @moewe I know this solution, but isn't it possible to extend the style so that this is done automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
     \map{
       \step[fieldsource=organization, final]
       \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval]
     }
  }
}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=3]{usera}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}
```

Since `organization` is a list `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` cannot properly deal with it. So we have to copy the contents to a field that is not a list (`usera` so we don't need to define a new datamodel). Then we can use it in `\labelelement` of `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected. `labelname` is something that is computed from authors or editors? Or why doesn't this interfere with the usual formatting?

Comment: @languitar Indeed `labelname` is generated from `author`s, `editor`s etc. according to `\DeclareLabelname`. My solution is just the standard definition of `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` with the line `\field[strwidth=3]{usera}` added in. I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean with 'why doesn't this interfere with the usual formatting?'

Comment: That's exactly the explanation I needed ;) I had suspected that you just extended the definition, but I wasn't sure how author etc. get into it.